# Extracting Data from a column based on symbols

Tags: r, regex

I have a tricky question that I'm hoping someone can help me with. I have an output file that looks pretty standard in that there is one value per row, per column - except for one column (excerpt below) that contains multiple entries per row:

```
4:103806204-103940896,4:103806204-103940896,4:103822084-103940896,4:103806204-103940896
7:27135712-27139877,7:27135712-27139877
2:209030070-209054773
1:16091458-16113084,1:16090993-16101715,1:16085254-16113084
16:70333061-70367735,16:70323669-70367735,16:70333061-70367735,16:70333061-70367735,16:70328735-70367735,16:70328699-70367735,16:70333061-70367735
```

It would be easy enough to split this column by `','` but then I won't be able to read it into, say, `R` very easily.

Instead, I'm hoping I can use a simple bit of code to select only the first two values, and then make one column into two, removing the rest. So the above would become the below:

```
4  103806204
7  27135712
2  209030070
1  16091458
16  70333061
```

I lose a little bit of info this way, but it makes the data more manageable. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try `library(stringr); do.call(rbind, lapply(str_extract_all(df$col, '\\d+'), function(x) head(as.numeric(x),2)))`

Comment: The output was NULL for a moment because of user error - I spelled the column name wrong. It works perfectly as is. If you add it as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)`.  We extract the numeric elements (`\\d+`) in a `list`, convert the 'character' class  to `numeric` and get the first two elements with `head`, `rbind` the `list` elements.

```
library(stringr)
do.call(rbind, lapply(str_extract_all(df$col, '\\d+'), 
         function(x) head(as.numeric(x),2)))
```

Comment: @RichardScriven My code is based on the assumption that `df <- read.table(text=x)`.  In the code change `df$col` as `df$V1`, I get 5 rows